Double сonsole output when running Flutter app on iOS (debug mode)
When I run my Flutter app on iOS in debug mode, the strings passed to the print method appear twice in the console. For example:
flutter:  Chat initialized
2024-09-27 04:42:12.944143+0300 AppName[625:16346] flutter:  Chat initialized

This issue occurs on my test device running iOS 15.8.3 but does not happen on another device running iOS 17.5.1. It does not happen on Android and iOS simulators. I'm running the app from VS Code with Xcode version 15.4.0.

did you used debugPrint or print?

I use print method

can you try with debugPrint?

I've just tried. The same result
